# Java Multithreading Wait for Task end

Tags: java, multithreading, task, executor

I'd like to ask you to help with this code. I have 10 instances of GameGeneratorController. Every instance is using method StartTaskCalculation(), which I'd like to create max  3 tasks(for type 1-2-3) . 
Method AddTask then add task to executor, which can handle 4 threads at the same time.

And the problem : I need to check, what calculation was sent to executor. 
For example, when I call AddTask(1), I want to wait till Calculation(1) is done, and only then call AddTask(1) again.

Now I can call StartTaskCalculation() 100 times in a row and 100 tasks will be added to executor.

I'd like to have max 30 tasks (10GameControllers * 3 tasks) in executor at the same time.
I tried to use Future.get() to get the result, but this will block other threads.

I need those 4 thread to run simultaneously and when one is done, give me some callback and let me know: "for this GameGeneratorController this Calculation(1) is done"

```
public class Main {   
     static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);      

     public static void main(String[] args) {

     GameGeneratorControllers[] controllers;
     for(1 to 10)   {
     controllers.add(new GameGeneratorControllers)
                    }
}



public class GameGeneratorController {

    public GameGeneratorController(int gameId, ExecutorService executor  )
    {
        this.gameId = gameId;      
        this.executor = executor;
    }
    ExecutorService executor;
    int gameId;


    public void StartTaskCalculation(){
        int Type = some logic to pick up from 1 , 2 or 3
        AddTask(Type);
    }

     public void AddTask(int taskType)
    {
        executor.execute(Calculation(int taskType));
    }

    void Calculation(int i){
        //some calculation here
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please read about Java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase for example.

Comment: ... and also for loop syntax: `for(1 to 10)   {` -- best to avoid "kind-of" / "sort-of" code and instead post the real thing.

Comment: Thans for info, I switched to java few days ago, in C# method names are PascalCase so I used it this way. For this for cycle, you are right, I thought it is not important.

Comment: Naming conventions are important because if your code conforms to expected standards, your code is easier to read and understand

Answer (score 2):

You have already have an ExecutorService. This is a big advantage because

> An Executor that provides methods to manage termination and methods
>   that can produce a **Future** for tracking progress of one or more
>   asynchronous tasks.

From [java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

With the future you can do

> Methods are provided to check if the computation is complete, to wait
>   for its completion, and to retrieve the result of the computation. The
>   result can only be retrieved using method get when the computation has
>   completed, blocking if necessary until it is ready.

From [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

With this you can made what you want. I hope this help you, you can found a lot of tutorials about this.

Comment: Thanks for info, but problem with future is (if I am understand it correctly) that while I am waiting for future.get- for one task, other thread(tasks) are not doing anything. "blocking if necessary until it is ready". I need all thread to work simultanously.

Comment: But this is  asynchronous tasks. Not Sync

Comment: @user10413093 if you have several futures and call `get()` on one of them it doesn't stop execution of futures. In blocks thread in which you call `get()`. So only one thread is waiting and all others are doing stuff